# Start a thread inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, python-multithreading

Im trying to execute a code with a structure like this:

```
import things
...
class MyThreadRead(Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        global cap
        global frame_resized
        global netMain
        ...
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame_resized = cv2.resize(...)

...
...
def YOLO():
    ...
    global frame_resized
    global cap
    ...
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(...)
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        readFrameThread.start()
        detections = detect(a, b, frame_resized, c)
        ...
    readFrameThread.join()
...
...
if __name__== "__main__":
    readFrameThread = MyThreadRead(1)
    YOLO()
```

When I execute this script, I get this error in the line of the function detections inside the YOLO function:

```
NameError: global name ´frame_resized´ is not defined
```

Where I should declare the global variable? Inside the YOLO function or outside?

Comment: You shouldn't be using global variables at all.

Comment: You can wrap it in a singelton class with thread save access of the attributes

Answer (score 0):

You should define it at global level like this

```
if __name__== "__main__":
    frame_resized = None
    readFrameThread = MyThreadRead(1)
    YOLO()
```

But better is to avoid using globals at all. There are many ways to do that, one is to create data container and pass it to all parties. it will look somehow like this:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = None
        self.frame_resized = None
        self.netMain  = None

class MyThreadRead(Thread):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container

    def run(self):
        ret, frame = self.container.cap.read()
        self.container.frame_resized = cv2.resize(...)

def YOLO(container, trd):
    container.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(...)
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        readFrameThread.start()
        detections = detect(a, b, container.frame_resized, c)
        ...
    trd.join()

if __name__== "__main__":
    container = Container()
    readFrameThread = MyThreadRead(1, container)
    YOLO(container, readFrameThread)
```

When selecting how to implement container, dont forget, `namedtuples` are readonly and not suitable for your case.

Comment: should I do the same with the cap object?

Comment: If you really want to use global variables, the answer is Yes, you should define them all.

Comment: And how can avoid the use of global variables if I need to share the frame_resized object with another thread? Because Im planning to use another thread to execute the detections function.

Comment: pass them as arguments

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion. Thanks all for the help.